# /bin/sh: 1: musl-gcc: not found when build openssl in rust image build progress

Tags: docker, rust

After I add the openssl dependencies in my rust project:

```
openssl = { version = "0.10.35", features = ["vendored"] }
```

the docker build process in github actions shows error like this(the base image is `ubuntu-latest`):

```
#14 24.82   RANLIBFLAGS = None
#14 24.82   running cd "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-3094ac8eb6135cf3/out/openssl-build/build/src" && AR="ar" CC="musl-gcc" RANLIB="ranlib" "perl" "./Configure" "--prefix=/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-3094ac8eb6135cf3/out/openssl-build/install" "--openssldir=/usr/local/ssl" "no-dso" "no-shared" "no-ssl3" "no-unit-test" "no-comp" "no-zlib" "no-zlib-dynamic" "no-md2" "no-rc5" "no-weak-ssl-ciphers" "no-camellia" "no-idea" "no-seed" "no-engine" "no-async" "linux-x86_64" "-O2" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-DOPENSSL_NO_SECURE_MEMORY"
#14 24.82   Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1u (0x1010115fL) for linux-x86_64
#14 24.82   Using os-specific seed configuration
#14 24.82   Creating configdata.pm
#14 24.82   Creating Makefile
#14 24.82 
#14 24.82   **********************************************************************
#14 24.82   ***                                                                ***
#14 24.82   ***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
#14 24.82   ***                                                                ***
#14 24.82   ***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
#14 24.82   ***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
#14 24.82   ***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
#14 24.82   ***                                                                ***
#14 24.82   ***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
#14 24.82   ***                                                                ***
#14 24.82   ***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
#14 24.82   ***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL file first)         ***
#14 24.82   ***                                                                ***
#14 24.82   **********************************************************************
#14 24.82   running cd "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-3094ac8eb6135cf3/out/openssl-build/build/src" && "make" "depend"
#14 24.82   running cd "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-3094ac8eb6135cf3/out/openssl-build/build/src" && MAKEFLAGS="-j --jobserver-fds=8,13 --jobserver-auth=8,13" "make" "build_libs"
#14 24.82   /usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
#14 24.82       "-oMakefile" include/crypto/bn_conf.h.in > include/crypto/bn_conf.h
#14 24.82   /usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
#14 24.82       "-oMakefile" include/crypto/dso_conf.h.in > include/crypto/dso_conf.h
#14 24.82   /usr/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
#14 24.82       "-oMakefile" include/openssl/opensslconf.h.in > include/openssl/opensslconf.h
#14 24.82   make depend && make _build_libs
#14 24.82   make[1]: Entering directory '/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-3094ac8eb6135cf3/out/openssl-build/build/src'
#14 24.82   make[1]: Leaving directory '/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-3094ac8eb6135cf3/out/openssl-build/build/src'
#14 24.82   make[1]: Entering directory '/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-3094ac8eb6135cf3/out/openssl-build/build/src'
#14 24.82   musl-gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wall -O3 -O2 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/local/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-3094ac8eb6135cf3/out/openssl-build/install/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_NO_SECURE_MEMORY  -c -o apps/app_rand.o apps/app_rand.c
#14 24.82   make[1]: Leaving directory '/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-3094ac8eb6135cf3/out/openssl-build/build/src'
#14 24.82 
#14 24.82   --- stderr
#14 24.82   /bin/sh: 1: musl-gcc: not found
#14 24.82   make[1]: *** [Makefile:671: apps/app_rand.o] Error 127
#14 24.82   make: *** [Makefile:175: build_libs] Error 2
#14 24.82   thread 'main' panicked at '
#14 24.82 
#14 24.82 
#14 24.82   Error building OpenSSL:
#14 24.82       Command: cd "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-3094ac8eb6135cf3/out/openssl-build/build/src" && MAKEFLAGS="-j --jobserver-fds=8,13 --jobserver-auth=8,13" "make" "build_libs"
#14 24.82       Exit status: exit status: 2
#14 24.82 
#14 24.82 
#14 24.82       ', /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openssl-src-111.26.0+1.1.1u/src/lib.rs:506:13
#14 24.82   note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
#14 24.83 warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
#14 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl" did not complete successfully: exit code: 101
------
 > [builder 6/6] RUN RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl:
24.82 
24.82 
24.82   Error building OpenSSL:
24.82       Command: cd "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-3094ac8eb6135cf3/out/openssl-build/build/src" && MAKEFLAGS="-j --jobserver-fds=8,13 --jobserver-auth=8,13" "make" "build_libs"
24.82       Exit status: exit status: 2
24.82 
24.82 
24.82       ', /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openssl-src-111.26.0+1.1.1u/src/lib.rs:506:13
24.82   note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
24.83 warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
------
Dockerfile:7
--------------------
   5 |     RUN rustup default stable
   6 |     RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
   7 | >>> RUN RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
   8 |     # RUN cargo build
   9 |     # do not use slim image, will block when query database
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl" did not complete successfully: exit code: 101
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl" did not complete successfully: exit code: 101
```

this is the dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM rust:1.54-bullseye as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN rustup default stable
RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
RUN RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

and this is the cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "alt-server"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
tokio = { version = "1.17.0", features = ["full"] }
diesel = { version = "2.0.4", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json"] }
reqwest = { version = "0.11.18", features = ["json"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
openssl = { version = "0.10.35", features = ["vendored"] }
```

the `main.rs` look like this:

```
fn main() {
    println!("hello world!")
}
```

what should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: How insistent are you on using Debian-derived images and Docker for this problem? I know exactly how I would solve this with Nix, but I don't do Debian.

Comment: (see f/e the `rust-hello-musl` example at https://discourse.nixos.org/t/building-rust-packages-against-musl/21345; need to change `x86-linux` to `aarch64-darwin` if you're trying to build a native MacOS binary, or `aarch64-linux` if you're building something to run in Docker on an Apple Silicon Mac, but it's otherwise roughly the right thing as-is).

Comment: (the important thing is that _Nix knows how to build OpenSSL as a static library against musl libc_, so nothing needs to be reinvented / there aren't concerns about whether you have that library precompiled; the `pkgsStatic` in that flake.nix files does the heavy lifting of making sure everything accessed through it is a static build; there's similarly a `muslCross` accessor to get a cross-compiling musl build stack)

Comment: ...that said, looking at what folks _outside_ the Nix world are up to, I see that the general advice from https://github.com/emk/rust-musl-builder is _not_ to use openssl if it at all can be avoided.